# Trying to get property of non-object shows even when it is an object Laravel5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Result extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'id_user', 'id_user');
    }

    public static function score($s, $c, $level, $semester, $session)
    {
        $ca = self::where([
                ['id_user', '=', $s],
                ['id_registered_course', '=', $c],
                ['id_level', '=', $level],
                ['id_semester', '=', $semester],
                ['id_session', '=', $session]
            ])->first();
        die(var_dump($ca));

        $exam = self::where([
                ['id_user', '=', $s],
                ['id_registered_course', '=', $c],
                ['id_level', '=', $level],
                ['id_semester', '=', $semester],
                ['id_session', '=', $session]
            ])->first()->exam;

        // die(var_dump($result));
        $totalScore = $ca;
        return $totalScore;
    }
}
```

I have the above code. If I try to access `$ca->ca`, it says trying to get property of non-object. But if I do `var_dump($ca)`, it shows that it is an object. Any clues as to what's wrong?

Comment: Can show the actual data?

Comment: Check if the function is getting called multiple times. May be `$ca` is not an object in a different call. Because, in case of die the script will stop and exit at the first time.

Comment: show what `var_dump($ca)` returns

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s5xsfCpy @JigarShah

Comment: can you provide your var_dump result?also i suggest that you use laravel's dd method instead of die(var_dump...))

Comment: can you try with `$ca[0]->ca` and also as @AliF mentioned  you should use `dd()` for checking results in laravel.

Comment: Using `$ca->ca` in a `var_dump` or `dd` or `print_r` doesn't throw any error, but assigning it to a variable or doing any other thing causes an error

Comment: Using `@` in front of `self` surpresses the error and the value I want doesn't throw error again. I think it's a false positive. @AliF @Jigar Shah

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to help

this is your result right?

```
object(App\Result)#272 (25) {
["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql"
    ["table":protected]=> NULL 
    ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" 
    ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" 
    ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) 
    ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) 
    ["exists"]=> bool(true) 
    ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) 
    ["attributes":protected]=> array(10) {
        ["id"]=> int(1)
        ["id_user"]=> string(36) "77760bc0-3c89-11e7-8d90-49b73785a136"
        ["id_registered_course"]=> int(5)
        ["ca"]=> int(40)
        ["exam"]=> int(60)
        ["id_session"]=> int(2)
        ["id_semester"]=> int(1)
        ["id_level"]=> int(1)
        ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-06-09 20:04:59"
        ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2017-06-13 16:49:11"
    }
    ["original":protected]=> array(10) {
        ["id"]=> int(1)
        ["id_user"]=> string(36) "77760bc0-3c89-11e7-8d90-49b73785a136"
        ["id_registered_course"]=> int(5)
        ["ca"]=> int(40)
        ["exam"]=> int(60)
        ["id_session"]=> int(2)
        ["id_semester"]=> int(1)
        ["id_level"]=> int(1)
        ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-06-09 20:04:59"
        ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2017-06-13 16:49:11"
    }
    ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL
    ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["events":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
    ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { }
    ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(1) "*" }
    }
```

Since you are using Laravel, i think you can use `$ca->__get('ca');` or `$ca->getAttribute('ca');`

if cannot, try `$ca->attributes['ca'];` or `echo '<pre>'; print_r($ca->toArray());die;`

Comment: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Comment: this one also? $ca->__get('ca');

Comment: Using `$ca->ca` in a `var_dump` or `dd` or `print_r` doesn't throw any error, but assigning it to a variable or doing any other thing causes an error

Comment: try echo '<pre>'; print_r($ca->toArray());die; what will be happened? @OshosanyaMichael

Comment: if cannot, try $ca->attributes['ca'];

Comment: Using @ in front of the `self::where` returns the object without any errors, really don't know why